# TCP flow control active waiting

Tags: tcp, transport-protocol, congestion

To perform flow control between a sender and a receiver during a TCP connection, the receiver includes in each packet to the sender, the size of available space ‘rwnd’ in its receiving buffer. This is useful to help the sender correctly throttle its transmission rate.

Considering the case where ‘rwnd=0’ and the sender has more data to send, the sender **actively** sends a dummy packet to test if more space is available in the receiver buffer to continue operations.

Why is an active waiting mechanism employed here, instead of having the receiver just **notify** the sender that its buffer is no longer full?

Comment: Packets get lost all the time. It is a fact of networking.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is an active waiting mechanism employed here, instead of having the receiver just notify the sender that its buffer is no longer full?

To prevent a deadlock.

Consider your scenario, where the receiver notifies the sender.  The sender has data to send, but the receiver is still processing data and sends a rwnd=0.

Now the receiver finishes processing the data, and tells the sender that it (the receiver) is ready for more data.  It sends a packet with the rwnd=x (some positive value), but the packet is lost due to some transmission or congestion error.

The sender is waiting for a nonzero rwnd value, but it never gets it.  So it waits forever, deadlocking the system.

Actively polling the receiver prevents this chain of events from happening.

Comment: But what if the protocol defines that the « notification » segment should be ACKed. Wouldn’t the reliable data transfer principle apply in that case?

Comment: The receiver’s ACK isn’t ACKed, otherwise you end up forever acknowledging previous acknowledgements.   But there are many ways to solve this problem. The developers picked one.

Comment: I mean when the receiver got more space in its buffer, it sends a segment to notify the sender that it is now able to accept more data. The sender needs to ACK that packet to confirm its reception. How can losses occur if we use the same mechanism of reliable data transfer that is used for other "normal" packets?

Comment: As I said, there is more than one way to solve the problem.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question unfortunately. I am aware that multiple ways exist to solve it, my doubts are why would the TCP designers choose the less optimized way? Having an active waiting helps in network congestion; and what if the receiving window stays full? Whereas a notification and its ack count up to 2 packets only.

Comment: You’ll have to ask the developers. You can read the minutes from the development committee. But we would just be speculating, which is off topic here.

Comment: If the receiver that is in a zero window condition now has receive space, what data would he send in a segment? To send a segment infers sending data, which has to be acked. So how would the servers app know this is not real data, but an indication that the receiver now has space? If that packet is lost, how will it be retransmitted? Things get really complex fast. 

Having the sender probe is simpler and ensures the path is still active. Plus, if the zwin condition takes too long, the sender can send a reset instead.